# C# Mongo DeleteMany - without using a class

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a normal (not GridFS) collection in a MongoDB I need to access to and delete some documents. I want/need to do this without using a class.

Have tried a few things yesterday/today and searched the web alot and tried a number of things.

Can't work out why deletemany isn't working for me. I have tried so many things I deleted all the code I tried and want to start fresh.

Are there decent examples some one can share a link to? or maybe some code example just here?

Thanks
Russell

Comment: can you share what you have tried and what didnt work. (codewise)

Comment: Hi MarcusLai, thanks, yes I supplied some code and mongo document in a reply to the answer by Ryan Gunner further below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the following would be the most convenient way. it uses the implicit operator to convert json string to filterdefinition. so no need for a class.

```cs
    var collection = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
                        .GetDatabase("test")
                        .GetCollection<object>("person");

    collection.DeleteMany("{ name : 'John Doe' }");
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Let me show you some concrete json/code as im still having issues.

MongoDocument
`code`
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5de....1008"),
    "ReceivedDate" : "04/12/2019",
    "ReceivedTime" : "08:40:45",
    "batch_id" : "10214",
    "EventMessage" : "SUCCESS - Received Submission",
}
`code`

Comment: The code
`code`
MongoClient db = DataBase.getMongoClientObject();
var GROUP = db.GetDatabase(DataBase.DatabaseName)
.GetCollection<object>("GROUP");
GROUP.DeleteMany("{ 'batch_id' : '10214' }");
`code`

I have tried without single quotes around batchid
e.g.
`code`GROUP.DeleteMany("{ batch_id : '10214' }");`code`

Thanks in advance
P.S. Would like to get the version working before I explore the other options.

Comment: @yogibear i just inserted the test document you posted into my db and used `GROUP.DeleteMany("{ 'batch_id' : '10214' }");` and it works. i think the problem is with the connection to the db. can you post the result of `db.GetDatabase(DataBase.DatabaseName).ListCollectionNames().ToList()`

Comment: thanks, yeah for some reason I wont bore you with, I managed to connect to wrong DB, I can see why. As soon as I checked the output from you suggestion, I could see the issue and have fixed it. All working now.

Many thanks to everyone for their replies and Ryan for your specific help. I should imagine one or two of the other methods I tried would have worked!

Answer (score 2):

This is the method i have used to delete many from my collections.

```
// Methods used in various places
internal static IMongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>(string collectionName)
{
  return db.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
}

// Your mongo entity CollectionTypeEntit
public class CollectionTypeEntity
{
    public const string COLLECTION_NAME = @"collectionName";

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId ID { get; set; }

    public bool propertyValue{ get; set; }

}

// Used in program to delete all records that match condition
GetCollection<CollectionTypeEntity>("CollectionName").DeleteMany(_ => _.propertyValue == true);
```

Note: db is instance of IMongoDatabase

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a `BsonDocument` and pass it to the driver's Delete methods where you would normally pass a `FilterDefinition`.

To delete all documents from a collection, use an empty `BsonDocument`:

```
await collection.DeleteManyAsync(new BsonDocument());
```

If you want to specify a query you can create a BsonDocument by hand:

```
var bson = new BsonDocument();
using (var w = new BsonDocumentWriter(bson))
{
    w.WriteStartDocument();
    w.WriteName("fieldName");
    w.WriteInt32(42);
    w.WriteEndDocument();
}
await collection.DeleteManyAsync(bson);
```

In this case it appears you can even create the collection by supplying `object` as the generic parameter:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<object>("Foo");
```