# How to delete all mongo documents in c# within particular time span

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongo-collection

I'm trying to delete mongo document from particular collection in c#

how i'm trying now is

```
            var document = collection.Find(_ => true).FirstOrDefault();  //get all the document

            foreach (var item in (dynamic)document)
            {
                if (item.Timestamp >= "")
                {
                    if ("Some Date" > Convert.ToDateTime(item.Timestamp))
                    {
                        collection.DeleteOne(item);   //delete document one by one
                    }
                }
            }
```

here i'm trying get all the document and delete one by one but there will be lot of documents to delete it can affect to performance so is there any way to direct delete mongo documents instead of get and delete in c#

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59160561/c-sharp-mongo-deletemany-without-using-a-class is this what are you looking for ?

Comment: @WhiteRom something like this but with some time span.

Comment: Is there any problem with adding filter (with TimeStamp field) inside deleteMany function ? Something like collection.DeleteMany({"Timestamp": {"$ne": ""}})